# app returning empty Toast

Tags: android, mysql, database

i am getting an empty Toast as response when i try to register a user to my sql database and no useful error hint is thrown in the logcat.

please what could possibly be the cause of this ?

`registerProcess`

```
 private void registerProcess(final String name, final String email, final String password) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_register";

    pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Functions.REGISTER_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response);
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                if (!error) {
                    Functions logout = new Functions();
                    logout.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());

                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString("email", email);
                    Intent i = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, EmailVerify.class);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    i.putExtras(b);
                    startActivity(i);
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    finish();

                } else {
                    // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                    // message
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("message");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to register url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("name", name);
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}

private void showDialog() {
    if (!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

private void hideDialog() {
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

web service

```
/**
 * Adding new user to mysql database
 * returns user details
 */

public function storeUser($fname, $lname, $email, $uname, $password) {
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
    $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, firstname, lastname, email, username, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$uname', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())");
    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        // get user details
        $uid = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
        // return user details
        return mysql_fetch_array($result);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no error in the code, as far as I can see.
You should check the response you get with **curl** and see, what is returned.

Answer (score 0):

to get the response from your web service you don't need JSON since you're doing a POST request by Volley. Your toast is empty because simply you're interpreting the response wrong and the objects like this one  `String errorMsg = jObj.getString("message");`  will be empty.

To get the response you should do like this :

```
if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("yourResponseFromTheWebService")) {

    ...
    Toast
} else if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("OtherPossibleResponse")){

    ....
    Toast

} else{

    ....
    Toast      
}
```

**EDIT :**

I managed to spot two things in your web service code.

1- why are you trying to get informations from the server of the same user when you just sent them from your app. That doesn't make sense. You should attach your data as extra to your intent as you did with the email.

2- Volley expects a String type response and you giving him different formats at the same time.

So this a modified version of your code :

**Web service :**

```
public function storeUser($fname, $lname, $email, $uname, $password) {
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
    $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, firstname, lastname, email, username, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$uname', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())");
    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        echo "successful";
    } else {
        echo "notsuccessful";
    }
}
```

**Android**

```
 private void registerProcess(final String name, final String email, final String password) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_register";

    pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Functions.REGISTER_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response);
            hideDialog();


                if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("successful")) {
                    Functions logout = new Functions();
                    logout.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());

                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    //add other informations you need like name ect..
                    b.putString("email", email);
                    Intent i = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, EmailVerify.class);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    i.putExtras(b);
                    startActivity(i);
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    finish();

                } else if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("notsuccessful")) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"new user wasn't registered successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to register url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("name", name);
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}

private void showDialog() {
    if (!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

private void hideDialog() {
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

**NOTE :**

if you wanna know the error from your Mysql request don't show it on your app, just check it in your browser.

I hope this works for you

Comment: can you show me how to fully apply this in my code? i'm still learning android. Thank you very much

Comment: can you show me what your web service is returning ? as I see from your code you have three possible responses ! true, false or message. Can you share the snippet code from your web service that returns those values ? so I can help you better

Comment: thank you very much for the tip. i just tried it now and no response is returned at all

Comment: try running your web service on a browser ! and see what you get back. If it's a blank page then there is a problem in your web service code , if you see successful or notsuccessful then I'll take an other look at the java code. Let me know

Comment: i have been running some test on my web service and it seems to be ok

Comment: when you pass the URL from `Functions.REGISTER_URL` in the browser do you get `successful` or `notsuccessful` ?

Comment: it's successful